# Pause CountDownTimer as long as the app is not visible

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a problem with my app. I have created a button called "browse". By clicking it, the button performs a google search and the app is no longer visible. Additionally, I have a `countdowntimer`. Now I want that the `countdowntimer` pauses as long as the app is not visible. 
Do you have any ideas?

I have already tried the methods `onPause();` and `onResume();` but its not properly working.

```
browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      String escapedQuery = null;
      resume = true;
      countDownTimer.cancel(); //I have no idea where to resume
      try {
          escapedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(begriff2, "UTF-8");
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + escapedQuery);
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

Comment: Why you think it did not work in onPause()?

Comment: The onPause function is not always executed, which is why sometimes the timer keeps running

Comment: The onPause() function is always executed , you can debug your app

Comment: Set your cancel countDwonTimer before super ,check my answer

Comment: If you are using a fragment use setUserVisibilityHint()

Comment: Ok the onPause function is working know but it seems like the onResume() function is executed instantly. Because when I add on Resume theCountDownTimer keeps running

Answer (score 1):

You can **cancel** it ,in `onPause()` , like this :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   countDownTimer.cancel();
   super.onPause();

}
```